# How to create multiple databases on same cluster of postgres operator?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I installed Crunchydata Postgres Operator on K8S by following this [link](https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/4.6.2/quickstart/#postgresql-operator-installer)

I found the following [link](https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/4.6.0/custom-resources/) to create PG Cluster.

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "pgocluster" {
  yaml_body = <<YAML
apiVersion: crunchydata.com/v1
...........
...........
...........
kind: Pgcluster
  ccpimage: crunchy-postgres-ha
  ccpimageprefix: registry.developers.crunchydata.com/crunchydata
  ccpimagetag: centos8-13.2-4.6.2
  clustername: ${pgo_cluster_name}
  **database: ${pgo_cluster_name}**
...........
...........
...........
YAML
}
```

With the definition mentioned above I would be able to create only-one database.

Is there any way to create multiple databases on the same cluster using 'custom-resource-definition' on Kubernetes ?

**EDIT:**

If `multiple databases` cannot be created on the same cluster, kindly let me know how to create `multiple clusters` using CRD

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to create multiple databases in the same cluster. I have used the below reference for pgo client to do that . First you need to create a superuser and then use that super user to create multiple databases in the cluster.
I havent used CRDs to create the databases if you are looking for that specific way to create databases.

https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/4.6.2/pgo-client/reference/pgo_create_cluster/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31500700)

Answer (score 0):

This snippet in the postgrescluster configuration will make sure you create 1 user and 2 databases

```
spec:
  users:
    - name: postgres
      databases:
        - databaseone
        - databasetwo
      options: "CREATEDB CREATEROLE"
```